# Entity Framework: Join Entities of Different Types and Order by Date

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've read a few articles that sound similar, but I wasn't quite able to grasp what was being discussed. I am using C# Entity Framework Code First and MVC 4. Here's an outline of some of the models hierarchically.

```
 Project
      ProjectImage
      ProjectDoc
           Comment
                CommentVote
                CommentReply
                     CommentReplyVote
```

All of those models have a DateCreated field. I want to run a query that I can order by date and show the newest to oldest of any of those events all in the same list. I want to handle (display) each one differently. I have no idea where to start, nor what search terms to use on Stackoverflow to find the answer.

Comment: Not controller events. The event is when it was created, i.e. the DateCreated field. So whether thats the project being created, the vote on the comment, the comment reply or whatever.

Comment: OK... I got the idea. I'm writing some code to show you how I'd approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I promised...

It's not state of the art but it's a simple Console Application that gives you an idea about how to approach this. I basically read from the lists (in your case, you'd read from the database tables). Then I add the `DateCreated` and the Object itself into a custom class that allows one to order all objects by the `DateCreated` field. The presentation code is up to you, but I show you how to print to the console according to the object type.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var projects = new List<Project>{
        new Project() {  ProjectId = 1, ProjectName = "My Secret Project", DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddHours(-1) },
        new Project() {  ProjectId = 2, ProjectName = "My Big Project", DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddHours(-2) }};

        var projectImages = new List<ProjectImage> {
        new ProjectImage() {  ProjectImageId = 1, ProjectImageSize = 17.17, DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddHours(-3) },
        new ProjectImage() {  ProjectImageId = 2, ProjectImageSize = 10.17, DateCreated = DateTime.Today.AddHours(-4) }};

        var objects = new List<MyCustomClass>();

        foreach (var project in projects)
        {
            objects .Add(
                new MyCustomClass() { DateCreated = project.DateCreated, Object = project });
        }

        foreach (var projectImage in projectImages)
        {
            objects.Add(
                new MyCustomClass() { DateCreated = projectImage.DateCreated, Object = projectImage });
        }

        // Objects ordered by Date, Newest first...
        var objectsByDateCreated = objects.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateCreated);

        foreach (var @object in objectsByDateCreated)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} => {1}", @object.Object.GetType().Name, @object.DateCreated));
        }

        // Displaying objects according to type
        foreach (var @object in objectsByDateCreated)
        {
            if (@object.Object is Project)
            {
                var project = @object.Object as Project;

                Console.WriteLine(project.ProjectName);
            }
            else if (@object.Object is ProjectImage)
            {
                var projectImage = @object.Object as ProjectImage;

                Console.WriteLine(projectImage.ProjectImageSize);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MyCustomClass
{
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public object Object { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectImage
{
    public int ProjectImageId { get; set; }
    public double ProjectImageSize { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But the sorting is being handled in memory and the questions specifically says EF.

Comment: From his question, where the order occurs doesn't matter in this case. Besides, I can't visualize another way of handling all this in the database server side in a single pass... :)

Comment: I don't know enough to know the difference between in memory and EF. This looks like exactly what I need though, once I get a chance to implement it I'll mark the answer as accepted. Are their drawbacks to "doing it in memory?"

Comment: @Jed: It won't be a major performance hit doing the ordering in memory provided that you don't have "millions" of records. If it's thousands you're good to go doing like I show you in this simple code. The main drawback is performance as you may have guessed. Doing a `UNION` as ivowiblo suggested is a difficult approach because the data sets must match ( table schema + number of columns, etc )... I don't even know if it's possible at all. When he said in EF, he meant doing the ordering in the database server side ( letting the server do the heavy lifting ). As I said I don't envision a way...

Comment: Thanks a million, with a little adjustment, this is working perfectly.... now to add in the other 6 actions!